# ValueError: "['f']" is not in list but it is

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have this dictionary, below, which I turn into a list:

```
alphabet_dict_lowerCase = {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'd': 4, 'g': 7, 'f': 6, 'i': 9, 'h': 8, 'k': 11, 'j': 10, 'm': 13, 'l': 12, 'o': 15, 'n': 14, 'q': 17, 'p': 16, 's': 19, 'r': 18, 'u': 21, 't': 20, 'w': 23, 'v': 22, 'y': 25, 'x': 24, 'z': 26}
```

list(alphabet_dict_lowerCase):

`['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'g', 'f', 'i', 'h', 'k', 'j', 'm', 'l', 'o', 'n', 'q', 'p', 's', 'r', 'u', 't', 'w', 'v', 'y', 'x', 'z']`

I am trying to see if `intersectionLetter` is in the list `list(alphabet_dict_lowerCase` using `index()`:

```
    for line in data:

        first_half  = line[:len(line)//2]
        second_half = line[len(line)//2:]

        first_half = [str(line) for line in first_half if line.strip()]
        second_half = [str(line) for line in second_half if line.strip()]

                    newList = []
        for element in second_half:
            if element in first_half:
                newList.append(element.split())
                intersectionLetter = ''.join(map(str, newList))
                print(intersectionLetter)
                print(str(newList))

                if intersectionLetter in list(alphabet_dict_lowerCase).index(intersectionLetter):
                    print(intersectionLetter)
```

intersectionLetter prints: `['f']`

Yet when I check with .index to see if `['f']` is in the list, it tells me it isn't there, when I can see it there...why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what is written, so `['f']` is a one element list.
You are checking if this one element list is in another list, but it isn't.
Extract this single element and reassign it like so:

```
intersectionLetter = intersectionLetter[-1]
```

Then you'll be checking if `f` str is in the list and I guess it should be there.

Just to show you an example of what is happening:

```
chars = ["s","r","t"]
s_element = "s"
s_list = ["s"]

s_element in chars <- this evaluates to True
s_list in chars  <- this evaluates to False
```